# Facebook Javascript - High Score API - Score is found but not able to return it

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am going through very strange issue. I want the high score of logged in user when they login in facebook, via FB api. I am using following code

```
    function returnhighscore()
    {
        FB.api("/"+FB.getUserID()+"/scores", 'get', {}, function(response) { 
          if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
          } else {
            var high_score1 = response.data[0].score;
            //document.getElementById("fbtestVal").innerHTML = response.data[0].score;
            return(high_score1);

          }
        }); 
    }
```

After FB load, i call this function. Strangly, this one is returning nothing but when i alert or console log the value within callback, it shows me score.

Can any one help?

Jacob

Answer (score 1):

Callback functions aren't supposed to return values. Rather, they should process whatever arguments are given to them, and possibly interact with higher scope variables.

In you case, I think you could declare a variable in the scope of your returnhighscore function, then make the FB.api call, update the value of this variable in your callback function, and finally return the variable (again in you function scope):

```
function returnhighscore()
{
    //declare variable in function scope
    var highscore = null;

    //call facebook api
    FB.api("/"+FB.getUserID()+"/scores", 'get', {}, function(response) { 
      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
      } else {
        var high_score1 = response.data[0].score;
        //document.getElementById("fbtestVal").innerHTML = response.data[0].score;

        //update value of function scope variable
        highscore = high_score1;
      }
    });

    //return updated value
    return highscore;
}
```

Comment: This is also true for closures. Expecting "return" to work in js like it does in java is the typical culprit for this kind of confusion.